# Google Cloud Composer 2 shows Unhealthy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

Anybody knows why is this happening? Which api composer calls to calculate health? What is this events?

GCP cloud composer 2 shows unhealthy but everything works. Seems like the service account cannot access an API to calculate health metrics.
Composer version composer-2.0.25-airflow-2.2.5

"Error from server (Forbidden): events is forbidden: User "xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
cannot list resource "events" in API group "" in the namespace airflow-2-2-5-11111111":
GKEAutopilot authz: the request was sent before policy enforcement is enabled" timestamp : '2022-10-07T15:48:08.834865950Z"
composer

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Wanted to know why is this happenning? How composer calculates the health metric?

Comment: Hi @Shawin, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer

Answer (score 2):

The environment health metric depends on a Composer-managed DAG named `airflow_monitoring` which is triggered periodically by the airflow-monitoring pod.

The `airflow_monitoring` DAG is a per-environment liveness prober/healthcheck that is used to populate the Cloud Composer monitoring metric `environment/healthy`. It is an indicator for the general overall health of your environment, or more specifically, its ability to schedule DAGs and run tasks. This allows you to use Google Cloud Monitoring features such as metric graphs, or setting alerts when your environment becomes unhealthy.

If this DAG isn't deleted, you can check the airflow-monitoring logs to see if there are any problems related to reading the DAG's run statuses. Consequently, you can also try troubleshooting the error in Cloud Logging using the filter:

```
resource.type="cloud_composer_environment"
severity=ERROR
```

You can find more information about the metric on the [GCP Metrics List](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-composer), and can explore the metric in [Cloud Monitoring](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/metrics-explorer).

Also, you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/monitoring-environments#environment) for information on Cloud Composer’s environment health metric.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The airflow monitoring dag runs successfully. I included the log info in my question. It seems like access issue on service account. This strange as the composer instance created through terraform.